# How to create user sessions events on flat table with user events

Tags: clickhouse

In Clickhouse I have a table listing events with a user id and events. My aim is to extract sessions with events from this data.

I looked at the documentation of the timeslot function, which describe a use case similar to mine, but I can't figure out how to write the query.

(https://clickhouse.yandex/docs/en/query_language/functions/date_time_functions/#timeslots-starttime-duration-91-size-93)

For example:

Condition to start next session is timeout more than 30 minutes

Events:

```
date                | user  | event
2018-12-21 00:00:00 │ user1 │ event1
2018-12-21 00:00:00 │ user2 │ event1
2018-12-21 00:15:00 │ user1 │ event2
2018-12-21 00:15:00 │ user2 │ event3
2018-12-21 00:30:00 │ user1 │ event4
2018-12-21 00:45:00 │ user1 │ event1
2018-12-21 01:45:00 │ user1 │ event2
```

What i want to get:

```
date                | user  | event  | session_id
2018-12-21 00:00:00 │ user1 │ event1 | user1_1
2018-12-21 00:00:00 │ user2 │ event1 | user2_1
2018-12-21 00:15:00 │ user1 │ event2 | user1_1
2018-12-21 00:15:00 │ user2 │ event3 | user2_1
2018-12-21 00:50:00 │ user1 │ event4 | user1_2
2018-12-21 00:55:00 │ user1 │ event1 | user1_2
2018-12-21 01:55:00 │ user1 │ event2 | user1_3
```

I tried to use arrays for it, but can't write the right query.

Here i try to find date when next session should be start

```sql
select user,
       groupArray(event) as event,
       arrayPopBack(groupArray(date)) as start_time,
       arrayPopFront(groupArray(date)) as finish_time,
       arrayMap(i -> (i + 1800), start) AS timeToNextSession,
       arrayFilter((x,y) -> x > y, finish_time,timeToNextSession) as endSessionTime
FROM user.events
group by user
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's try this query:

```sql
SELECT r.1 date, r.2 user, r.3 event, r.4 session_id, arrayJoin(result) r
FROM (
  SELECT
      user,
      groupArray(event) AS events,
      groupArray(date) AS dates,      
      /* an array of rounded dates */
      arraySort(groupUniqArray(roundedDate)) AS roundedDateArray,
      /* an array of rounded dates shifted to 30 minutes (where 30 min taken from timeSlot-function) */
      arrayMap(i -> (i + 1800), roundedDateArray) AS shiftedRoundedDateArray,
      /* to intersect two arrays to find the dates when sessions start */
      arrayFilter(x -> (has(shiftedRoundedDateArray, x) = 0), roundedDateArray) AS sessionStartDateArray,
      /* get sessions sorted in descending order */
      arrayReverse(sessionStartDateArray) reversedSessionStartDateArray, 
      /* define the session_id  */
      arrayMap((index, sessionStart) -> (concat(toString(user), '_', toString(index)), sessionStart), arrayReverse(arrayEnumerate(reversedSessionStartDateArray)), reversedSessionStartDateArray) sessions,
      /* prepare the result */
      arrayMap(i -> (dates[i], user, events[i], arrayFirst(s -> dates[i] >= s.2, sessions).1), arrayEnumerate(events)) AS result      
  FROM
  (
      SELECT date, timeSlot(date) AS roundedDate, user, event
      FROM
      (
          /* the source data */
          SELECT
              arrayJoin([('2018-12-21 00:00:00', 'user1', 'event1'), ('2018-12-21 00:00:00', 'user2', 'event1'), ('2018-12-21 00:15:00', 'user1', 'event2'), ('2018-12-21 00:15:00', 'user2', 'event3'), ('2018-12-21 00:30:00', 'user1', 'event4'), ('2018-12-21 00:45:00', 'user1', 'event1'), ('2018-12-21 01:45:00', 'user1', 'event2')]) AS a, toDateTime(a.1) AS date, a.2 AS user, a.3 AS event
      )
      ORDER BY user
  )
  GROUP BY user)
ORDER BY user, date  

/* Result
┌────────────────date─┬─user──┬─event──┬─session_id─┬─r──────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ 2018-12-21 00:00:00 │ user1 │ event1 │ user1_1    │ ('2018-12-21 00:00:00','user1','event1','user1_1') │
│ 2018-12-21 00:15:00 │ user1 │ event2 │ user1_1    │ ('2018-12-21 00:15:00','user1','event2','user1_1') │
│ 2018-12-21 00:30:00 │ user1 │ event4 │ user1_1    │ ('2018-12-21 00:30:00','user1','event4','user1_1') │
│ 2018-12-21 00:45:00 │ user1 │ event1 │ user1_1    │ ('2018-12-21 00:45:00','user1','event1','user1_1') │
│ 2018-12-21 01:45:00 │ user1 │ event2 │ user1_2    │ ('2018-12-21 01:45:00','user1','event2','user1_2') │
│ 2018-12-21 00:00:00 │ user2 │ event1 │ user2_1    │ ('2018-12-21 00:00:00','user2','event1','user2_1') │
│ 2018-12-21 00:15:00 │ user2 │ event3 │ user2_1    │ ('2018-12-21 00:15:00','user2','event3','user2_1') │
└─────────────────────┴───────┴────────┴────────────┴────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
*/
```

Use ClickHouse for session definition doesn't look like an optimal way.

I would calculate the *session-id* on server-side before writing data to CH (calculation *session-id* on client-side is valid point too). Let's consider some points of this way:

- take any storage-engine that supports the sliding expiration policy for a stored item (for example, Redis)
- the key of an item is the unique user-id (or smth like this)
- the item stores the session-id
- any incoming event before be stored to ClickHouse should get session-id from this storage
- any incoming event either initiate the creation of an item in storage (when it doesn't exist and start 'new session') or prolong the lifetime of the existing item (aka session).